# Combine stored procedure and query in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, dml

How do I combine executing of a stored procedure and using its result or parameters in a regular SQL query?

For example I would like to do something like the following:

```
-- passing result of SELECT to SP
SELECT a, b FROM t
EXEC my_sp a, b

-- passing result of SP to INSERT    
INSERT INTO t
EXEC my_sp a, b
```

etc.

Comment: Can you rewrite your question? It doesn't make much sense in it's current form.

Comment: @JohnFx: I'm asking about all possible combinations of SP and DML. Why it has no sense?

Comment: No offense, I just think that the meaning of your question is getting lost in the somewhat poor translation to English.

Comment: @JohnFx: It would be very nice if you could rewrite it a bit to increase the sense according to the idea I described above

Comment: He's asking a common question: is there a way to use the output of a stored procedure as a subquery. He's also asking the reverse: is there a way to pass the results of a subquery as a parameter to a stored procedure.

Comment: @egrunin: You're absolutely right!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

no, you need to use a temp table

```
create table #results (col1 int, col2 varchar(5) ...)

INSERT INTO #results
   EXEC YourProcedure @parma...
```

then you can join to it

```
SELECT
    *
    FROM YourTable     y
        JOIN #results  r ON ...
    ....
```

if you don't know the columns and data types from the procedure you can use this excellent answer: [Insert results of a stored procedure into a temporary table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/how-to-select-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure/1228165#1228165)

In brief it uses `OPENROWSET` to execute the stored procedure into a #temp table that is created on the fly, without the need to name and know the type all the columns.

Answer (score 4):

If your SP can be rewritten as an inline table valued UDF, these typically perform very well and are equivalent to a parametrized view.  ITVF can be used any place you would use a table or view.

If your SP won't work as an inline TVF (local variable manipulation required), it may work as a multi-statement TVF (contains a BEGIN/END) which may or may not perform poorly depending on what you have to do.

After your SP has been turned into a UDF, you can then still call the UDF from your SP (SELECT* FROM udf(params)) or elsewhere it can be used for joins, etc, so all your code is inside the UDF - no duplication.