# can you join on a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a bunch of `WITH` statements:

```
;with OneAccession as (
        select client_id,COUNT(patient_id) PatientCount from
        (
            select client_id,patient_id
            from F_ACCESSION_DAILY
            group by CLIENT_ID,PATIENT_ID
            having COUNT(ACCESSION_ID)=1
        ) a
        group by CLIENT_ID
    )
    ,

    TwoAccessions as (
    select client_id,COUNT(patient_id) PatientCount from
        (
            select client_id,patient_id
            from F_ACCESSION_DAILY
            group by CLIENT_ID,PATIENT_ID
            having COUNT(ACCESSION_ID)=2
        ) a
    group by client_id
    )

    ,

    ThreeAccessions as (
    select client_id,COUNT(patient_id) PatientCount from
    (
        select client_id,patient_id
        from F_ACCESSION_DAILY
        group by CLIENT_ID,PATIENT_ID
        having COUNT(ACCESSION_ID)=3
    ) a
    group by client_id
    )
etc
```

And I join these statements on

```
select * from myTable
join OneAccession
on...
join TwoACcessions
on...
join ThreeAccessions
```

Instead of having all those `with` statements, can i just create a stored proc? I would just pass the value of `having count(accession_id)=**@myParam**` and do this:

```
select * from myTable
join storedproc(1)
on...
join storedproc(2)
on...
etc...
```

**Is there an issue on joining on a stored Proc?** Is my methodology OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **not** join on a stored procedure, but you can join both a function and a view.  Note that a view can not take parameters and that a function may not be as performant as the CTE.

Also, looking at your query, it looks like you should look into the new windowing functions and that something like

```
;with cte as (
    select *, count(*) over (partition by client_id, patient_id) patientcount
    from f_accession_daily
)
select * from myTable
     inner join cte on ... and patientCount=1
```

might help with what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: thanks so much can you please show me how select *, count(*)....is equivalent to having count...?

Comment: Added some code that shows the simularity.  As others have pointed out, a TVF is what you are describing, but given your code I would spend some time seeing if there's not a different approach.  Without knowing your schema and data I of course can't say for sure, but I think it's unlikely that your approach is the best solution to whatever problem you are attempting to solve.

Comment: im sorry, what would i be joining on and what would i be counting?

Comment: The count, for each row, is the number of rows with that patient and client id's, the difference s that instead of group by, you have partition by, and you can include any or all of the other columns in the table, without going back and doing a self join.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [`APPLY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Using `APPLY` with [table-valued functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) seems to be the classic example for using `APPLY`, and I think it's what you want.

Have a look at this [blog post](http://bradsruminations.blogspot.com/2009/07/cool-cross-apply-tricks-part-1.html) with an example (using AdventureWorks):

```
select f.FirstName
      ,f.LastName
      ,f.JobTitle
      ,f.ContactType
      ,cc.CardNumber
from Sales.CreditCard cc
join Sales.ContactCreditCard ccc on cc.CreditCardID=ccc.CreditCardID
cross apply dbo.ufnGetContactInformation(ccc.ContactID) f
where cc.ExpYear=2008
  and cc.ExpMonth=6
  and cc.CardType='Vista'
```

Comment: and what are your thoughts on this solution? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2563175/117700

Comment: I think the correct question would be `"What is the diff between TVF and stored proc"`, which is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254814/sql-server-table-valued-functions-vs-stored-procedures

Answer (score 1):

No...you can do this using a table function instead though.

Comment: See this post: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/167399/Using-Table-Valued-Functions-in-SQL-Server. Once the table function is created you can use it like a table using joins/applys.